# Unable to unlock login.keychain ( Jenkins build )

Tags: ios, jenkins

I'm trying to build app via jenkins, but this is the line where it crashes:

```
[ios] $ /usr/bin/security list-keychains -s /Users/admin/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
[ios] $ /usr/bin/security default-keychain -d user -s /Users/admin/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
Will not set default: file /Users/admin/Library/Keychains/login.keychain does not exist
security: SecKeychainSetDomainDefault user: write permissions error
[ios] $ /usr/bin/security unlock-keychain -p ******** /Users/admin/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
security: SecKeychainUnlock /Users/admin/Library/Keychains/login.keychain: write permissions error
FATAL: Unable to unlock the keychain.
```

Weird thing is that it shows that this file doesn't exists - it is probably because of permissions to file, but I was unlocking this keychain in Keychain manager.

When I changed path to login.keychain ( after importing it ):

```
Cleaning build directory: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/iOS-build/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos
[ios] $ /usr/bin/security list-keychains -s /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
[ios] $ /usr/bin/security default-keychain -d user -s /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
[ios] $ /usr/bin/security unlock-keychain -p ******** /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
[ios] $ /usr/bin/security show-keychain-info /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
Keychain "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/Library/Keychains/login.keychain" no-timeout
===========================================================
== Available provisioning profiles
[ios] $ /usr/bin/security find-identity -p codesigning -v
     0 valid identities found
```

And it ends with this error:

```
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “xxxx”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.
```

Of course under Xcode everything works just fine..

Comment: Do you run Xcode as the Jenkins user?

Comment: Weird; you shouldn't be getting permission denied errors then.  I run my Jenkins using a separate user to avoid the pain involved with this process (I login as that user and import the keys using the Keychain app).

Comment: but right now I've added login.keychain to jekins user keychain list. And after that I've tried to connect to jenkins and..well, nothing has changed.

Comment: When I've tried managing keychains for "build users" (not just Jenkins) in the recent past I've found it almost impossible.  A lot happens under the hood so I've found it easier to use the Keychain Access app to do this (including adding permissions to use the keys).

Comment: You mean using keychain first aid?

Comment: I don't know what that is.  Bottom line is that I made my Jenkins user a fully-fledged developer, getting the certificates working first in Xcode (as that user) before even using the automated Jenkins bit.

Comment: any chance that You would write exactly what have You done?

Comment: Well just imagine someone call "Timothy Jenkins" joined your development team.  Do what you'd do for Timothy.  Create a user for him, use Xcode to install the certificates, check-out the source and make sure it compiles and runs.  Then install Jenkins in Timothy's home directory and start configuring it.